# Is it advisable to use an SD from Pi Zero in a Pi Zero W?

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have an SD card which was painstakingly set up with various functionality (e.g. necessary packages, settings, etc...) on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

Now I want to replace the Zero with the Zero W (so I don't need to use the WiFi dongle).

I am pretty sure that I can take the SD card from the Zero and place it into the Zero W and it would just work.

My question is whether it's advisable.  Are there performance implications?  Other possible issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Raspbian images should work in all models (provided they have been updated with suitable kernel/firmware).

It is, of course, possible to install incompatible software or configuration, but any reasonable settings work.